# eval-when-compile not being honored?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm attempting to install ace-jump-mode for emacs 24.1.50.1.

I've installed it with M-x package-install, and calling M-x ace-jump-mode activates it and prompts for a letter, but upon entering a letter, I get the error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: every
```

Running `emacs -q` (and then running `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa")` like I have in my .emacs file) allows me to load ace-jump-mode and it functions without an issue. Assuming thus that the error exists in my .emacs, I commented out everything in my .emacs, and reopened emacs regularly, but still get the error.

From some searching around, I think the issue is the code in ace-jump-mode.el

```
(eval-when-compile
  (require 'cl))
```

is not working correctly when I don't use `emacs -q`. When I M-x load-library cl, everything works fine.

I imagine that since I can't find any references to this online, its not a common bug, so it must be an issue with my config. I know I could just load cl in my .emacs, but I don't see the need to load the entire package just for one function.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Or, how to load only one function from cl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs is self documenting, <kbd>C-h f every</kbd> will show you that this
function is defined in `cl-extra` not `cl`, but loading `cl` autoloads it, so
it does become available.

Some things with how `cl` is loaded may have changed with Emacs 24, which
broke this library, I'm not certain.  Like you found out, the easiest fix is
to just

```
(require 'cl)
```

in your init file.  This isn't as a big deal as you make it out.  A **lot** of
libraries you might use will do this anyway, so it's likely you're just
changing the order things get loaded.

The alternative is to just submit a patch to the author of `ace-jump-mode`
that avoids using `every`, which is more inconvenient.

Finally, if you ever got `ace-jump-mode` to work it was because you loaded the
uncompiled ".el" file instead of the compiled ".elc" file, which would have
run `(require 'cl)`, meaning that both `cl` and `cl-seq` will have been loaded
somewhere along the way.  So there is no magic that can make this work
without loading those files.

Comment: You can also add `(byte-compile-disable-warning 'cl-functions)` to disable warnings when you byte compile your `.emacs`.

Answer (score 3):

`(eval-when-compile <foo>)` means that `<foo>` is only executed when compiling the file (or when running it uncompiled).  So if you compile your file, the resulting file won't load `cl`, which is a problem since `every` is only defined when `cl` is loaded.  `(eval-when-compile <foo>)` is used to load *macros* (such as `ignore-errors`), since these are only needed during compilation, but `every` is not a macro, hence your problem.

Comment: Is there an alternative to eval-when-compile that would make it work here?

Comment: @Josh: Yes, just don't put anything around the `(require 'cl)`